# What c# datatype should oapi string with format of base64 be?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am using the Rest API Client Generator extension for Visual studio on a yaml file that has a string property with format of base64.

```
    File:
      type: string
      format: base64
      description: Represents the content of an uploaded file. Should be base64 encoded.
```

The generator creates a byte array for this property like so:

```
public byte[] File { get; set; }
```

Is this a bug, or is adding this format supposed to mean something very different than what I expected? I think it should generate a string, right?